# [PHP]how to count a row in join table

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to count the number of row in a table.

i have the following code

```
$sqlPS = "SELECT o.id_order, o.tanggal_order, o.status_order,
                        d.jumlah_cetak, 
                        b.harga,
                        m.nama_lengkap

                        FROM order_data o, detailorder d, member m, cetak_foto b

                        WHERE
                        d.id_order=o.id_order
                        AND m.id_member=o.id_member
                        AND b.id_cetak_foto=d.id_cetak_foto
                        AND o.tanggal_order BETWEEN '$tgla' AND '$tglb'
                        ";
```

How to count the number of row in a table?
thanks

I tried : $sql_pd=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_order) FROM order_data ");
$get=mysql_num_rows($sql_pd); result =1. i have 3 record data

Comment: FYI: There is no question in this post

Comment: Ever consider `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`? Without an explicit relationship, any count will be meaningless

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the PHP, so with PDO you can count the rows like:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare($sqlPS);
$q->execute();
```

<strike>**Method 1:**</strike>

```
// Return all the rows
$q->rowCount();
```

**Method 2:**

```
$result = $q->fetchAll();
count($result);
```

> mysql_* will be deprecated deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, You should use
>   the following according to your query.

```
$sql_pd=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_order) id FROM order_data ");
$result= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_pd);
$total_rows = $result['id'];
```

**OR**

```
$sql_pd=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_data ");
$total_rows= mysql_num_rows($sql_pd);
```

**Note: According to comment of @Mike Brant** rowCount() is not available across all databases, so method 2 will help to count the total number of rows.

Comment: rowCpunt is not available across all databases so be warned that this solution is not potable.

Comment: I tried : $sql_pd=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_order) FROM order_data ");
$get=mysql_num_rows($sql_pd); result =1. i have 3 record data

Comment: thank you @jogesh_pi problem solved. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @PanjiFatri Thats great, now you should close this thread to accepting the answer.